# Scala split behaviour: consecutive occurrence of split pattern

Tags: string, scala, split

Using Scala's standard `String` library:

`"a,,,".split( "," )`  is

`Array(a)` , and not

`Array( a, "", "", "" )`

as one would expect. Is there any way to force this?

`"a,,,b".split( "," )` is

`Array( a, "", "", "", b )` which is fine.

I'd be surprised if this is a bug, so does anyone understand the purported logic behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) of `split` method we can read:

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

But you can use `split` method with additional `limit` parameter. For example:

```
"a,,,".split( "," ,-1)
```

Setting negative number as `limit` parameter will cause that pattern will be applied as many times as possible.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) for details